# Erro ao criar postagem Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Olá,

Tive uns probleminhas com um vírus cross-domain(SEO infect) em minha hospedagem, depois de limpar, reconfigurar as coisas o meu wordpress está apresentando um erro que é novo para a minha pessoa, no lugar da caixa onde você digita o seu conteúdo aparece "Atualmente você está editando a página que exibe seus posts mais recentes."
Alguem sabe como corrijo? Não estou conseguindo indentificar se é no banco de dados que eu arrumo ou se é em algum arquivo.

[image: Erro]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vá em **Configurações -> Leitura** e selecione outra página no select **"Página de posts"**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse aviso aparece justamente porque como essa página está selecionada ali, o conteúdo dela vai ser substituído pela sua lista de posts.

Answer (score 0):

Eu atualmente não posso comentar, mas a respostas da Marta Freitas é perfeita!
Funcionou para mim!

O erro aconteceu ao importar a base de dados pra outro servidor.

Porém, por algum motivo estranho não precisava de todos os comandos, eu tive que ir testando um por um (porque adicionar todos no phpMyAdmin fazia parar em certo porto). Mas foi super bem!

Então pra mim a resposta foi essa mesmo:

```
DELETE FROM wp_termmeta WHERE meta_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_ID=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_links WHERE link_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_users WHERE ID=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE umeta_id=0;

ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_terms ADD PRIMARY KEY(term_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy ADD PRIMARY KEY(term_taxonomy_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_comments ADD PRIMARY KEY(comment_ID); 
ALTER TABLE wp_links ADD PRIMARY KEY(link_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_options ADD PRIMARY KEY(option_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_users ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID); 
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID); 
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(umeta_id);

ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_terms CHANGE term_id term_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy CHANGE term_taxonomy_id term_taxonomy_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_comments CHANGE comment_ID comment_ID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_links CHANGE link_id link_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_options CHANGE option_id option_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_users CHANGE ID ID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_posts CHANGE ID ID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta CHANGE umeta_id umeta_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score -2):

Tive o mesmo problema em um blog e a causa era a configuração das tabelas do wordpress no banco de dados. A tabela **wp_posts** não estavam com **chave a primária** no ID e **AUTO_INCREMENT**. Devido a isso toda vez que você tenta adicionar um novo post/página é gerado o ID 0 que causa a mensagem de erro.

Como tem que ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para a correção você deve alterar as tabelas, pode utilizar os comandos abaixo:
***P.s: Em algumas tabelas, configurei a PK atraves do painel no PhpMyAdmin (Seleciona a tabela > estrutura > seleciona a coluna > chave primária.***

```
DELETE FROM wp_termmeta WHERE meta_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_ID=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_links WHERE link_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_users WHERE ID=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=0; 
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE umeta_id=0;

ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_terms ADD PRIMARY KEY(term_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy ADD PRIMARY KEY(term_taxonomy_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_comments ADD PRIMARY KEY(comment_ID); 
ALTER TABLE wp_links ADD PRIMARY KEY(link_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_options ADD PRIMARY KEY(option_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id); 
ALTER TABLE wp_users ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID); 
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID); 
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(umeta_id);

ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_terms CHANGE term_id term_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy CHANGE term_taxonomy_id term_taxonomy_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_comments CHANGE comment_ID comment_ID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_links CHANGE link_id link_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_options CHANGE option_id option_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_users CHANGE ID ID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_posts CHANGE ID ID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta CHANGE umeta_id umeta_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```